# Merge R row together, removing NA's

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe in R that looks like

```
data.frame(ID = c(1,1), a = c(1, NA), b = c(NA, 2), c = c(NA, 3))
```

so the rows are mutually exclusive. Also not that some of the columns are characters.

What I need is to have only one row per ID.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

```r
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1), a = c(1, NA), b = c(NA, 2), c = c(NA, 3))

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

df %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), \(x) x[!is.na(x)]),
            .by = ID)
#>   ID a b c
#> 1  1 1 2 3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Hope one of the base R tricks could help

```
> aggregate(. ~ ID, df, na.omit, na.action = na.pass)
  ID a b c
1  1 1 2 3
```

or

```
> list2DF(as.list(colMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE)))
  ID a b c
1  1 1 2 3
```

or

```
> data.frame(t(colMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE)))
  ID a b c
1  1 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can `discard` the `NAs`, in an operation grouped `.by` `ID`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df |> 
    summarise(across(everything(),
                     \(x) discard(x, is.na)),
              .by = ID)
  a b c
1 1 2 3
```